# Is there a word for describing something by what it is not?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a word for describing something by what it is not?

For example if I describe a thing as odorless, tasteless, and colorless.

The context is that of describing something divine.

Comment: This happens to be the correct context. If you submit the comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Apophatic**

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/apophatic)

> "Christian theology; of or relating to the belief that God can only be
>   described by a process of negation"